# How do I convert this cURL command to PHP (libcurl)?

Tags: php, command-line, curl, translation

In continuation off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982973/how-do-i-begin-with-making-a-small-cross-site-ajax-script-using-someones-api), what are the PHP statements I need to accomplish this:

```
curl -is -F 'J:A-login=BTDT::Action::Login' -F 'J:A:F-address-login=EMAILADDRESS' -F 'J:A:F-password-login=PASSWORD' http://hiveminder.com/splash | grep -o 'JIFTY_SID_HIVEMINDER=[0-9a-f]\+'
```

The flags and fields are still mysterious, and I've not the time presently to swim through docs to figure out how this translates.  I do at least understand the `| grep ...` portion, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need curl for that:

```
$data = array(
    "J:A-login"             => 'BTDT::Action::Login',
    "J:A:F-address-login"   => 'EMAILADDRESS',
    "J:A:F-password-login"  => 'PASSWORD',
);
$context = stream_context_create(
    array( 
        'http' => array( 
            'method'  => 'POST', 
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => http_build_query($data), 
            'timeout' => 10, 
        ), 
    )
);

$ret = file_get_contents('http://hiveminder.com/splash', false, $context);
if (preg_match('/JIFTY_SID_HIVEMINDER=[0-9a-f]+/m', $ret, $matches)) {
    //see $matches[0]
}
```

Note that this might need modifications; checking the form at http://hiveminder.com/splash, it seems to require something more complicated than what your curl line uses.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering what all this cURL business was for, anyway.  Thanks a ton!